# beamer hyperref url with %20 runaway argument

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I want to use a URL in beamer notes. If the URL includes a `%20` it seems to cause xelatex trouble.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
 \note{\href{http://www.example.com/A%20B%20C.pdf}{some text}}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Gives the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
\note {\href {http://www.example.com/A\end {frame} \par \end {documen\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \frame.
<inserted text>
                \par
<*> test

?
```

Looking at other questions on this site seems to suggest that the use of `%20` is OK in a link, so I am not sure what to do. I want a `%20` rather than a space.

Comment: Did you try with `\%`?

Comment: No! I read a lot of answers that seemed to suggest it shouldn't matter. Adding them appears to fix the problem. I'll try testing on a real URL.

Comment: It doesn't matter with different classes than `beamer`, because each frame is absorbed as the argument to a macro; it also matters when `\href` is itself in the argument to another macro. So in this case it matters twice! `;-)`

Comment: Aha, that explains why it worked when I tried it outside `beamer`. Could you make your answer (both comments) into an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no problem, generally, when

```
\href{http://www.example.com/A%20B%20C.pdf}{some text}
```

appears by itself, that is, not in the argument to a macro, because `\href` suspends the usual TeX's reading rules when absorbing the URL. However, something like

```
\mbox{\href{http://www.example.com/A%20B%20C.pdf}{some text}}
```

would give troubles (`\mbox` is used to stand for any command with argument) because TeX's reading rules are *not* suspended when `\mbox` absorbs its argument.

In this case, you can escape the percent character:

```
\mbox{\href{http://www.example.com/A\%20B\%20C.pdf}{some text}}
```

because `\href` knows how to transform `\%` in a real percent character when making the internal URL.

On the other hand, with `beamer` you cannot use the “naked” form, because the contents of a `frame` environment is absorbed as if it were the argument to a macro, so it would be the same as in the `\mbox` situation. Nevertheless, the input

```
\begin{frame}
\note{\href{http://www.example.com/A\%20B\%20C.pdf}{some text}}
\end{frame}
```

should work.

---

As an aside, take the habit of typing `\end{frame}` without any space before it in the same line, because if you add the `fragile` option to `\begin{frame}`, a space before `\end{frame}` would produce weird errors.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I've always wondered about this. In my case the problem appears with `url`s in bibliography entries, when they are processed by Biber. Do you know if there's any way of making this work without escape characters? I ask because I often access directly those urls from my bibliography file (via Emacs's `browse-url`).